# change event not working for a textbox when the value is assigned externally

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onchange

I have a textbox and a button.
When I click the button, it sets certain value in the textbox.
I want to submit the page whenever the value of the textbox is changed.

Please check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/soumyazyx/GTpRC/4/)

HTML:

```
<input type='text' class="set" size=50>
<input type="button" id="click" value="Click" />
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
        alert("Changed!");
    });
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $('.set').val('Why am I not getting the alert saying  - Changed! ');
    });
});
```

I am able to trigger the change event when I am editing the textbox content.I know that the change event gets triggered when the textbox loses focus.This is not the case when I am changing the value by button click.

I have seen answers which monitors the textbox for change at a specified time interval , say 0.1 sec.

Is there no other way for this to be done. 
Thanks.

***EDIT - 1***
**Sorry for not being clear** in my original post itself.

My requirement is to trigger an event whenever the inputbox content is changed - Not necessarily by the click of a button.I have added a button just to explain the problem.
The change may be due to any reason.

So,the code(inside the button click function)

```
$('.set').val('Hello').change();
```

will not solve the problem.
Hope I am clear this time.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Fire the event manually after setting the value using the `change()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
        alert("Changed!");
    });
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $('.set').val('Why am I not getting the alert saying  - Changed! ');
        $('.set').change();  //Manual fire of event.
    });
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/RUdu2/

Comment: hi Kevin,the solution suggested by you doesnt actually solve my problem(my problem description was not clear I guess ). I have edited my question. The content of the textbox can change due to any reason...not only because of a button click.So,I need to have some event handler attached to textbox itself.Attaching .change() to buttonclick event wont be helpful here.  Any thoughts ?? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically changing the value of an input doesn't fire its change event. You'll have to do that yourself using `.trigger('change')` (or just `.change()`) at the same time as changing its value:

```
$('.set').val('Why am I not getting the alert saying  - Changed! ').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this, when you are setting or changing the value of the text input chain it with `.change()` too:

```
 $("#click").click(function () {
    $('.set').val('Why am I not getting the alert saying  - Changed! ').change();
  }); //-------------------------------------this one here-------------^^^^^^^^^
```

So whenever you set the input value this way the change event will be triggered right after click.

---

May be this could help

```
$("input").on('change keyup', function () {
    alert("Changed!");
});
```

Comment: Hi Jai,Thanks for your reply.But this is not actually my requirement.I have edited my question.Please have a look.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the value of `.set` programatically, so the event doesn't fire. You have to trigger it manually:

```
$('.set').val('Why am I not getting the alert saying  - Changed! ').change();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
        Submitform();//Function for submitting form
    });
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $('.set').val('Why am I not getting the alert saying  - Changed! ');
        Submitform();//Function for submitting form
    });
});
```

Function for submitting the form

```
function Submitform(){
$("#YourformId").submit();//Submits your form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve like

```
$('.element').val('value').change(function(){
      $("#form").submit();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/senstar2/CHjL5/5/