# on change doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have input type file of array that user can click add more.In my code part javascript i have method on change

```
    jQuery('.focus_image').on('change', function () {
            alert("hello");
```

above code i test input type file when user click add new input type file and browse file in directory but i test already input type file name orange work perfectly but name banana doesn't show hello What code is wrong? Help me to solve this problem.Below is my full code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="test">test</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <div id="popup1">
                <div id="image-zone" style="width:200px;float:left;text-align:center">
                    <input type='button' class='button-primary' value='Add' id='add_focus'>
                    <input type="file" class="focus_image" name="orange">
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var count_focus = 0;
                var num_focus = count_focus;
                var temp_focus = count_focus + 1;
                var name_focus = 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus;

                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                    $("#add_focus").click(function() {
                        if (num_focus == 10) {
                            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                            return false;
                        }
                        id_div = 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus;
                        file_id_name = "file_Focus_DIV" + temp_focus;
                        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus);
                        newTextBoxDiv.html('<input type="file" id="' + file_id_name + '" name="banana" class="focus_image">');
                        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#image-zone");
                        temp_focus++;

                        name_focus = 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus;
                        num_focus++;

                    });

                });
                //Below code is doesn't work when add new input type file
                jQuery('.focus_image').on('change', function() {
                    alert("hello");
                    //                  
                });
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Problem can solve**
This problem can solve by in code html add new element dynamically must re register event

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033953/change-event-not-working-for-a-textbox-when-the-value-is-assigned-externally

Comment: You should keep that code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`.

Comment: It does't work and i try to test input type file name orange (static not add more) when i click browse file out put show hello but input type file name banana (add more input)doesn't show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look on Below jsfiddle for your code**

http://jsfiddle.net/guNvz/

Actually Problem with little arrangement. If you add new element in HTML by dynamically than on that element you need to re register that event.

Try with below script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var count_focus = 0;
            var num_focus = count_focus;
            var temp_focus = count_focus + 1;
            var name_focus = 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus;

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                jQuery("#add_focus").click(function() {
                    if (num_focus == 10) {
                        alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                        return false;
                    }
                    id_div = 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus;
                    file_id_name = "file_Focus_DIV" + temp_focus;
                    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus);
                    newTextBoxDiv.html('<input type="file" id="' + file_id_name + '" name="banana" class="focus_image">');
                    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#image-zone");
                    temp_focus++;

                    name_focus = 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus;
                    num_focus++;
             jQuery('.focus_image').unbind('change').change(function() {
                alert("hello");
                //                  
            });
                });

            });
            //Below code is doesn't work when add new input type file


    </script>
```

Let me know you have query.

Thanks..!!

Comment: this way you are unbinding all of the change events from all of the focus_image inputs and then reattaching it again, the correct way would be to use on and have it bubble to the container which would be the best way to do it. `$('#image-zone').on('change', '.focus_image', function() {`

Comment: <input type="file" class="focus_image" name="orange"> doesn't show hello but add new input type file name banana and browse file then browse file orange again then show hello what should i do for the first click input type file name orange then show hello?

Comment: Ok i solve already i move the code out of scope $("#add_focus").click(function () ^_^

Comment: What is the meaning of this line ?           
jQuery('.focus_image').unbind('change').change(function() {
                alert("hello");

Comment: @Vivek : If any change event register on `focus_image` class than it un-register first. so that on one select two same event not register. if you dont unbind that that's event perform more time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `on` like that, use it like this, using it on `#image-zone` will attach this event to anything that has css class `focus_image` on `#image-zone` now and if they are added dynamically.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#image-zone').on('change', '.focus_image', function() {
  // Your code
 });
 // Your other code like the click event
});
```

Test out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zRrGz/) which shows how you should do it

Comment: @user2006362: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: It does't work and i try to test input type file name orange (static not add more) when i click browse file out put show hello but input type file name banana (add more input)doesn't show

Comment: @sergioadh, you need not to put it in `document` ready function if you using `on` on `document` itself. And using `on` on `document` should be avoided. Its same as `live`

Comment: @Jashwant taking from jquery documentation "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers." http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @sergioadh Jashwant saying you not to use `on` on the `document`. ofcourse `live` is deprecated which is other story.

Comment: @Jashwant maybe not attach to document but at least the idea is that using on like this will work with dynamic html, it could be done with '#image-zone' to avoid performance issues.

Comment: I was saying that `on` on `document` is like using `live`. Every event anywhere in the whole `document` is to be checked. `live` was deprecated on similar grounds.

Answer (score 0):

use this, to rule out that it's a css problem

```
  $('#banana').focus(function() {
      alert('Handler for .focus() called.');
    });
```

Comment: input type file name orange work but input type file name banana doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

**Keep that `on` event function inside the ready function**

Here is the modified code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="test">test</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <div id="popup1">
                <div id="image-zone" style="width:200px;float:left;text-align:center">
                    <input type='button' class='button-primary' value='Add' id='add_focus'>
                    <input type="file" class="focus_image" name="orange">
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var count_focus = 0;
                var num_focus = count_focus;
                var temp_focus = count_focus + 1;
                var name_focus = 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus;

                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                    $("#add_focus").click(function() {
                        if (num_focus == 10) {
                            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                            return false;
                        }
                        id_div = 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus;
                        file_id_name = "file_Focus_DIV" + temp_focus;
                        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus);
                        newTextBoxDiv.html('<input type="file" id="' + file_id_name + '" name="banana" class="focus_image">');
                        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#image-zone");
                        temp_focus++;

                        name_focus = 'Focus_DIV' + temp_focus;
                        num_focus++;

                    });
                    //keep the code here
                    jQuery('.focus_image').on('change', function() {
                        alert("hello");
                        //                  
                    });
                });
                //Below code is doesn't work when add new input type file
                //Removed the code from here
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7b8Q/)**