# Cannot launch script on dynamically added element

Tags: jquery, html

This is pretty much the same problem as in here: [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) , but that post was a few years old, and it's solution did not work for me.

I have a small image carousel, which works properly when I add it directly to html, but when I add it dynamically the jQuery click event for buttons does not work. I tried changing from `button.click()` to `button.on("click,function(){})` but it still doesn't work. Can someone tell me 
a) How to make it work
b) How does modyfying DOM affects jQuery execution, so I understand it better in the future (for example, are there some DOM element jquery ignores?)

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".carousel-button-left").on('click',function(){
    var $ul=$(this).next().find(".carouselUl");;
    //alert(""+$ul.html());
    var $lastchild=$ul.children().last();
    $ul.prepend($lastchild);
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".carousel-button-right").on("click",function(){
    var $ul=$(this).prev().find(".carouselUl");
    //alert(""+$ul.html());
    var $firstchild=$ul.children().first();
    $ul.append($firstchild);
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16033998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use event delegation for registering handlers for dynamically added elements.

Just using `.on()` does not make the event registration delegation based, the parameter and the element to which the handler is attached is important

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', ".carousel-button-left", function () {
        var $ul = $(this).next().find(".carouselUl");;
        //alert(""+$ul.html());
        var $lastchild = $ul.children().last();
        $ul.prepend($lastchild);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".carousel-button-right", function () {
        var $ul = $(this).prev().find(".carouselUl");
        //alert(""+$ul.html());
        var $firstchild = $ul.children().first();
        $ul.append($firstchild);
    });
});
```

the set of elements on which the handler is added(LHS of `.on()` call) should be present in the dom when the script is executed, then we need to use a second parameter in the `.on()` call to specify the target element selector which are present under the LHS elements.

Comment: It worked. Could you plese explain why previous options did not work?

Answer (score 3):

try changing:

```
$(".carousel-button-left").on('click',function(){
...
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.carousel-button-left', function(){
...
```

so that jQuery receives the event and delegates it the element that matches the selector provided as argument.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click',".carousel-button-left",function(){
    var $ul=$(this).next().find(".carouselUl");;
    //alert(""+$ul.html());
    var $lastchild=$ul.children().last();
    $ul.prepend($lastchild);
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".carousel-button-right",function(){
    var $ul=$(this).prev().find(".carouselUl");
    //alert(""+$ul.html());
    var $firstchild=$ul.children().first();
    $ul.append($firstchild);
    });
});
```